# Writing out a single register in Assembly

Tags: assembly, printing, masm, cpu-registers, irvine32

Fairly simple question this time. How do I write to screen the contents of a single register in Assembly? I'm getting a bit tired of calling DumpRegs just to see the value of one register.

I'm using x86 architecture, and MASM in Visual Studio, and Irvine32.lib.

Comment: When asking assembly language programming questions you should specify which CPU architecture you're targetting. And also which specific tools (assembler, simulator, ...) you're using if that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm using x86 architecture, and MASM in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Irvines's `DumpReg` uses repeatedly a macro of `Macros.inc`: `mShowRegister`. It can be used directly. Example:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE Macros.inc

.code
main PROC

    mov esi, 0DeadBeefh
    mShowRegister ESI, ESI

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

A documented macro with more options is [`mShow`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Fmacros32%2Fmshow.htm). Example:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE Macros.inc

.code
main PROC

    mov esi, 0DeadBeefh
    mshow ESI, h

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

Irvine32 has output functions that take a value in EAX, such as `WriteDec` (unsigned base 10).

See the documentation http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writedec.htm which has links to WriteHex (hex = base 16), and WriteInt (signed base 10).

These functions use the Irvine32 calling convention and preserve *all* registers, including the arg-passing register EAX, so you can even insert them as a debug-print for EAX at least.  More usually you'd use them as simply normal output functions.

Usually for asm debugging you'd use a debugger, not debug-print function calls.