# Need help so that it prints out "42"

Tags: assembly, x86

```
segment .data
num1: db 40
num2: db 2
num3: db 44

segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
        enter   0,0               
        pusha

        mov     eax,[num1]
        add     eax,[num2]
        call    print_int
        call    print_nl

        mov     eax,[num3]
        sub     eax,[num2]

        call    print_int
        call    print_nl

        popa
        mov     eax, 0            
        leave
        ret
```

The code above was given

This prints out 623652394
1143264298

My professor says to use **dump_regs** macro to make this print "42" and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: `db` is only 1 byte, but you load 4.  You probably want `dd`, or use `movzx` load and byte operand-size for add or sub.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181320/writing-out-a-single-register-in-assembly

Comment: @IronMan: Printing registers isn't the problem.  This is getting the wrong values into regs in the first place by doing a dword load that overlaps multiple bytes.

Comment: "db" was a given input. My professor wants me to start with that.

Comment: Ok, then do a byte and sub instead of dword, or do zero-extending loads with movzx like shown in [Loading a register from a "db 0" doesn't load a 0 into EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43014135)

Comment: [Average of marks with bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52541787) shows how to use movzx with `db` to do math after zero-extending.